# Is there a program to limit access to Steam?

Tags: steam

I would like to help myself control how many video games I play. Is there a way I can block Steam at certain times of day or after using it for so long?

Comment: Blocking doesn't seem likely, since any program you have permission to enable to block you, you would have permission to disable as well.  But maybe all you really need to shoot for is a reminder that you've exceeded your goal amount of time.

Comment: Do what my mother used to to when I was younger and just becoming game addicted: Set a kitchen timer. When it goes off, get off. It will take more self-discipline, but if you can stick to it, it makes you a better person, too. Plus, cheap solution! =D

Comment: Related (and in the same vein as @Kendra's comment): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/how-do-i-limit-my-gaming

Answer (score 1):

Short of parental software, you could try either of these:

- Take your steamapps folder, and compress (or store it (ie no compression) it using 7zip/winrar. Have someone you trust make up a password, and when you've finished working then have them unlock the archive. The *steamapps* holds your games if you didn't know.
- Uninstall Steam, but keep the *steamapps* folder (%Steam Directory%/steamapps/). When you're done with your work simply reinstall Steam, and you start playing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GameNanny](http://www.gamenanny.org/) to control when you can play Games and when not. I never used and I actually don't want to encourage anyone to use since I do not know if this program is safe or not. It seems like that it is safe, due to many [users using](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2286985) it. It also seems to be Open Source.

However, do use it at your own risk and make sure Steam Guard is on and your email account has a different, but secure password.